# How can I show custom posts to my subdomain base network site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, web-development-server

I made a multi-network WordPress website.
Example site,
The main site is: domainname.com
The network subdomain site is: demo.domainname.com
There are custom posts on my main site. How can I show those custom posts to my demo.domainname.com network site?

Answer (score 0):

> With the help of database query you can get custom posts easily.

//or

you can use below plugin and activate in network admin so with this plugin is available in both of your sites and you can create post type easily without any coding.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: So i need to query for the custom post in my network subdomain site theme?

Comment: you can easily make database connections and get data.

Comment: @MuktarAli hope my idea helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you have another idea to display data you can share with me so i will be surprised. :)

Comment: Yes i seen it. any another method?

Comment: Ok Thank you :)